# Ice Sliding Puzzle Path Finding Shortest Distance

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding

Consider a problem similar to this: [Ice Sliding Puzzle Path Finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170368/ice-sliding-puzzle-path-finding)

Except that I wish to find the optimal shortest path algorithm. I've looked into it and found that BFS, A* and Djikstra's are all viable algorithms, but I need some advice on which would be best for my scenario or if there's a better choice.

My scenario being where an ice maze similar to the one in the stackoverflow question exists and is in a txt file. For the data structure holding the grid I thought to use a 2D char array since I thought it would perform best but maybe simplicity isn't the way to go here.But I'm clueless as to whether more fitting data structures exist

With that taken into account which of the three algorithms do you guys think would perform best on one of these mazes given that they'd be say max 2560x250 in size with varying complexities in the possible paths.

Concerns with BFS - non-optimal path storage approach, considers each tile moved a step so one path could be sliding along step by step while another is taking steps in different directions with shorter slides ( don't know the performance impact it will have)

Concerns with A* & Dijkstra's - Forming all possible nodes and edges with weights could be a heavy process

simple example maze txt (0 - wall, S - Start, F - Finish)

```
.0...00...
.0F0......
..0..0....
.0.0.....0
..........
..........
....0.0.0.
.0.0......
0........0
S.0.....00
```

Comment: @PaulHankin I can see DFS being faster since movement would be done in one go until reaching a stop, in comparison to BFS taking a step at a time but, correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't DFS return only one path? If used to find the shortest path wouldn't it have to trace all paths increasing the time taken exponentially?

Comment: Your problem is that you have a graph with weighted edges, and you need to find a shortest path from A to B. (You have an additional initial problem, which is to construct the graph from the textual representation). It's possible to construct the graph in linear time, and then Dijkstra can find the shortest path in O(|V|log|V|) time (|E| <= 4|V| here, so the +|E| term in the complexity isn't significant). BFS and DFS are not appropriate solutions here (ignore what I said before, I misread the problem), because they're not designed to find shortest paths in a directed weighted graph.

Comment: 2560*250 = 640,000, and there's at most 4 edges per node, so your graph representation will use megabytes of storage, which is about 3 orders of magnitude less memory than a modest, modern computer has. You have to be careful to construct the graph in linear time -- if you naively trace directions from each square independently you'll get quadratic behavior. Perhaps this is what you meant by "heavy process"?

Comment: Thanks for the input! In that case I will give Dijkstra a shot and see where it takes me! Constructing the graph from the text is definitely a hurdle, I've seen people on the internet say to take tiles adjacent to walls as nodes since they're likely to be "reachable" and work out the edges from there somehow,the other way I can think of is to completely explore the maze (doesn't seem efficient), but it seems challenging.
Either way thanks for the help, if I'm unable to construct the graph I may have to make another post but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it!

Comment: I see, I'm not very knowledgeable with regards to the construction of graphs so I'll have to look into what would be the best approach, and yes that is what I meant.

Comment: You're overthinking optimizations because you think the problem is big, but it's small. Just write simple code to explore the whole maze and see if it's too slow, and if it is then figure out which part is slow. I've given you a clue about where possible quadratic behavior might slip in, which is something you should consider if constructing the graph is slow (although I didn't give you a solution to that, so you'll have to solve that problem yourself, if it is indeed a problem).

Comment: Ah ok, I'll take that to heart and get to work on writing a simple constructor and worry about optimization if it is indeed slow, thank you again for the thorough and informative responses.